# Liaison Delta ECS Batching

Tags: message, aggregation, delta

Does anyone know if Liaison's ECS product has the capability to aggregate messages together based on a filter criteria and process them after all of the messages have been received?

I need to listen for flat file data messages, read the order number in the flat file and an integer in the flat file that represents how many flat files will be generated for that order number, and then once all of the flat files have been processed I need to map them into a single outbound EDI transaction message (one outbound message per order number).

A standard aggregation pattern; please note I am not asking about EDI batching, which is something different.

Is this something that can be done using ECS functionality, or does an external batching system need to be created?

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow. It would be really nice if you can post your efforts. It would become easier for the people to debug.

Comment: Ankur, its a yes or no question. If you know the product, does it support message aggregation? All my efforts are directed toward building an external batching application, which is what I want to avoid.